# Load part of JSON file with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am writing a webapp which reads a huge JSON file. However, each time I make a request it loads the entire file using ajax and then takes out the part which I want. Is there a way that I can just load a part of it, similar to how you can just load a certain HTML ID or class?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: You have two options: Have your serverside code (which might be PHP, or something else) read the JSON and cut out a part of it, or switch to using a Database format of some sort, and have your serverside code return JSON of just part.

Comment: *"similar to how you can just load a certain HTML ID or class"* well.. you can't do that either without the server doing it for you, so...

Comment: Pass some arguments to the server when you request the JSON, and have the server-side script use those arguments to reduce the JSON to just the part you want.

Comment: @KevinB I think he's talking about [loading page fragments with `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) (It may be worth noting that the *entire* page is being downloaded in that case, but only the desired fragment is being added to the current page.)

Comment: yes, that's my point. that using .load in that way actually does what he's trying to avoid.

Comment: So is there a problem with loading it once and just reading from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

Split up your json file into smaller more manageable chunks.

or

Use API to parse it server side and return the component needed.

or

Store the json client side.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I must have 50 reputation to comment; I do agree it's not much of an answer.

Comment: well... it does kinda list out the three possible ways to solve this problem. why can't it be an answer?